# How do I include a json file in the output build of QT Project

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

I'm new to QT Creator.  I have added a .json file and a couple .txt files to my QT C++ Project and I can see the files in my project window.  When I clean, run qmake and then build all, I'm expecting these files to be copied to my output directory, but they aren't there.  I checked my .pro file and I do have the entries

**OTHER_FILES += \
    MyJsonFile.json \
    MyTxtFile.txt \
    ReadMe.txt**
(Note: each file name is on a separate line)

How do I get these files to copy to my output directory when I do my build?  I want the program to have access to them as soon as it starts.  I saw in the QT documentation that it said you can to Add New > General > Text File but the docs only say you can see the file in the project window.  They do not explain how to get them to copy to your build and I can't find the answer anywhere.  Im using QT Creator 3.0.1 based on QT 5.2.1 on a Windows 7 box.  Thanks for any guidance.

EDIT: P.S. I am hoping that I can keep the json and text files out of the app so that I can change values in the files at runtime, or between program executions and just have the project pull the new values when it starts.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty, but do you need to add the OTHER_FILES list to DEPLOYMENT somehow?

Comment: Yeah, that "somehow" is what Im looking for.  I know in Eclipse, Visual Studio and other IDEs you can do something like "include in build" or "copy to output dir" etc, but I dont see a way to do that in QT Creator.  I now almost nothing about makefiles and would think it shouldnt be this difficult to get a txt file to copy over to your build dir.  Or is it?  Thanks!

Comment: The build process for a project described by a `.pro` file has nothing to do with Qt Creator. It is a two stage process: first the makefiles are generated by qmake, then the build is done by the make tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build and install directories are separate concepts. If you merely build, you should not expect anything to get actually installed.

In Qt Creator, when you have a qmake-based project, the default build setup invokes `make`. To install, you need to then invoke `make install`. This can be added as an additional build step in the project's "Build and Run" tab.

With qmake, there is no default location for the install directory, and no objects are declared to be installed, so `make install` is a no-op by default.

The files to be installed need to be:

1. Set up as a qmake object.
2. The object has to be added to the `INSTALLS` variable.

For example:

```
# Sets the default installation prefix to the build directory.
# This is the same default that Qt's configuration process uses.
!defined(PREFIX,var): PREFIX = $$OUT_PWD

MY_RESOURCES = \
  MyJsonFile.json \
  MyTxtFile.txt \
  ReadMe.txt

OTHER_SOURCES += $$MY_RESOURCES

# Object describing the resources to install
my_resources.path = $$PREFIX/share/myproject
my_resources.files = $$MY_RESOURCES

# The automatically generated object describing the target.
target.path = $$PREFIX/bin/myproject

# Declare my_resources and target objects to be installed.
INSTALLS += my_resources target
```

The user or package manager script is supposed to give
the desired install prefix to qmake. A complete build done in
an empty build directory (a so-called shadow build) would look like:

```
# on Unix
qmake "PREFIX=/usr/local" /sourcedir/myproject.pro
# on Windows (the installation into Program Files won't
# be done by make, but by an installer!)
qmake /sourcedir/myproject.pro
make
make install
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Kuba but its early and a little over my head.  Is there somewhere I can read on how to use make.  When I build I get a folder that includes three files named Makefile, Makefile.Debug and Makefile.Release.  There are also two other folders inside named debug and release.  Is this just a build or is that an install?  Is there any way to have the file copy over when I do a build so that I dont have to keep manually moving it?  My program needs to read from that file at runtime.

Comment: @Shawn: The folder you get after build is the build folder that's done after the `make` call. You need to either manually run `make install` from that folder, or have Qt Creator add it. Go to left side of the window, Projects pane, look up your project's tab on the top, select "Build and Run" subtab, and add an extra build make step with `install` as the sole argument. You'll then get the `bin` and `share` folders there (since the prefix was simply the build folder). You can give the prefix argument to qmake, so that it installs elsewhere (say in $HOME).

Comment: I will give this a try.  Thank you so much Kuba Ober for the thorough listing of steps!  Will I still be able to debug using the install step?

Comment: One last question Kuba Ober, is this a Custom Build Step?  And do I type "make" as the command and "install" as the argument?  Thanks

Comment: You can simply have it as a "make" build step, of course custom will work too. Debugging an installed binary requires you to select the proper binary in the "run" tab. Qt Creator will by default debug the built binary, not the installed one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a resource file. Simply create a resource file and add your files to it. When you build your app you will always have those file within the executable.
To be honest I don't know how work with QtCreator because I have always used eclipse with the plugin. I can suggest reading an article : [Managing Resources](http://doc.qt.digia.com/vs-add-in-1.1.7/vs-addin-managing-resources.html)

**EDIT**
After my answer the OP told me that those file will be changed at runtime.. so my answer is clearly not what he want. Someone can tell me what to do with this answer? thanks.

Comment: I was really hoping to not have the file compiled into the app so that I could change values in the json at runtime.  Thanks for the article.  I will definitely give it a read.

Comment: ehm..this is not a little detail. Resource file are for static files.. something that doesn't change so often. Please explain what you have to do and we can help..

Comment: My apologies.  Im getting a crash course in QT and forgot to add that piece of the puzzle.  Basically, I just want a json file that gets copied over to the build dir.  That's all.  I'm reading that file once the program starts, but I want to be able to change some values in the file before I run it and have my program read those changes each successive load.

Comment: Andrea.marangoni, your answer was helpful and I may be able to use it for a different problem Im having.